# How do you calculate the average gradient direction and average gradient strength/magnitude

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

In OpenCV how do you calculate the average gradient strength in a `Mat` and the average gradient direction?

I have sourced the below methods by googling but I want to confirm I am actually doing this correctly before moving onto the next step.

Is this correct?

```
Mat img = imread('foo.png', CV_8UC); // read image as grayscale single channel

// Calculate the mean intensity and the std deviation
// Any errors here or am I doing this correctly?
Scalar sMean, sStdDev;
meanStdDev(src, sMean, sStdDev);
double mean = sMean[0];
double stddev = sStdDev[0];


// Calculate the average gradient magnitude/strength across the image
// Any errors here or am I doing this correctly?
Mat dX, dY, magnitude;
Sobel(src, dX, CV_32F, 1, 0, 1);
Sobel(src, dY, CV_32F, 0, 1, 1);
magnitude(dX, dY, magnitude);

Scalar sMMean, sMStdDev;
meanStdDev(magnitude, sMMean, sMStdDev);
double magnitudeMean = sMMean[0];
double magnitudeStdDev = sMStdDev[0];


// Calculate the average gradient direction across the image
// Any errors here or am I doing this correctly?
Scalar avgHorizDir = mean(dX);
Scalar avgVertDir = mean(dY);
double avgDir = atan2(-avgVertDir[0], avgHorizDir[0]);


float blurriness = cv::videostab::calcBlurriness(src); // low values = sharper. High values = blurry
```

Answer (score 3):

Technically those are the correct ways of obtaining the two averages.

The way you compute mean direction uses weighted directional statistics, meaning that pixels without a strong gradient have less influence on the average.

However, for most images this average direction is not very meaningful, as there exist edges in all directions and cancel out.

If your image is of a single edge, then this will work great.

If your image has lines in it, containing edges in opposite directions, this will not work. In this case, you want to average the double angle (average orientations). The obvious way of doing this is to compute the direction per pixel as an angle, double them, then use directional statistics to average (ie convert back to vectors and average those). Doubling the angle causes opposite directions to be mapped to the same value, thus averaging doesn’t cancel these out.

Another simple way to average orientations is to take the average of the tensor field obtained by the outer product of the gradient field with itself, and determine the direction of the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue. The tensor field is obtained as follows:

```
Mat Sxx = dX * dX;
Mat Syy = dY * dY;
Mat Sxy = dX * dY;
```

This should then be averaged:

```
Scalar mSxx = mean(sXX);
Scalar mSyy = mean(sYY);
Scalar mSxy = mean(sXY);
```

These values form a 2x2 real-valued symmetric matrix:

```
|  mSxx   mSxy  |
|  mSxy   mSyy  |
```

It is relatively straight-forward to determine its eigendecomposition, and can be done analytically. I don’t have the equations on hand right now, so I’ll leave it as an exercise to the reader. :)

Comment: *"Doubling the angle causes opposite directions to be mapped to the same value, thus averaging doesn’t cancel these out"* — can you explain why doubling angles prevents them from annihilation?

Comment: @theV0ID If you have two unit vectors pointing in opposite direction, and add them up, you end up with a zero vector. If you first double their angles, they will now both point in the same direction (take any two vectors, do the computation, and verify this statement!), and adding them up will yield a length two vector. Doubling the angle is writing the vector in polar coordinates, and doubling the angle value.